# Iterate through a list and append results to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract boxscore NFL data from sportsreference. When you call the boxscore data for a single date you get a bunch of stats in multiple columns in a single row.  So I'm trying to iterate through multiple dates for boxscores from a list and then append each row to the same dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from sportsreference.nfl.boxscore import Boxscore

boxscore_list = ['201909080mia', '201909150rav', '201909220kan', '201909080phi', '201909150atl']

   for x in boxscore_list:
     game_data = Boxscore(x)
     df = game_data.dataframe
```

The only thing that happens with my current code is that I get the last boxscore in a single row.  I'm not sure how to go about getting all the boxscores to append to one dataframe when they iterate through the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append the dataframes otherwise df keeps getting overwritten.

```
dfs = []

for x in boxscore_list:
    game_data = Boxscore(x)
    df = game_data.dataframe  
    dfs.append(df)

result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly!!  I was at my wits end trying to append the records.